# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' - bundle.js not serverd

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, reactjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a new version of our react website in the morning to our AWS beanstalk development server and something went very wrong.
I got a SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' from the deployed version. Then I decided to deploy the old version, but that gave the same error. After a lot of trying around I ended up terminating the environment and cloning my production environment to create a new development server, but still the problem is there.

Basically the cloned environment fails, while it works fine on the production server.

The only other strange thing I noticed to far is that when I do `wget http://phoodster-web-dev.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/bundle.js` it returns the `index.html` instead of the `bundle.js` file, while our production server does it correctly.

Any idea what is wrong?

Update:
The reason why the bundle.js looks like the index.html is, because the bundle.js was obviously not compiled.
In the nodejs log I might have found the reason:

> ERROR in ./~/react-geosuggest/module/input.js Module not found: Error:
>   Cannot resolve module 'react-addons-shallow-compare' in
>   /var/app/current/node_modules/react-geosuggest/module  @
>   ./~/react-geosuggest/module/input.js 15:33-72
>
> ERROR in ./~/react-geosuggest/module/suggest-list.js Module not found:
>   Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-addons-shallow-compare' in
>   /var/app/current/node_modules/react-geosuggest/module  @
>   ./~/react-geosuggest/module/suggest-list.js 13:33-72
>
> ERROR in ./~/react-geosuggest/module/suggest-item.js Module not found:
>   Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-addons-shallow-compare' in
>   /var/app/current/node_modules/react-geosuggest/module  @
>   ./~/react-geosuggest/module/suggest-item.js 13:33-72

Still very strange, why it fails only on the new clone and not the main server.

Comment: A `script` tag in a .js file?

Comment: You have put HTML code into Javascript file. Reference error is on line `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: When you open your `bundle.js` located here - http://phoodster-web-dev.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/bundle.js , You could only see html content instead javascript blocks. Check and resolve that.

Comment: You have a complete HTML page in that JS file what Javascript code on that page would you like to display?

Comment: Well that is exactly my problem, our production server returns as expected the bundle.js file and not the code from the index.html. Nothing I have done.

Comment: @Trollbrot there is no relevant javascript code in the http://phoodster-web-dev.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/bundle.js what is the javascript code that you need there are parts of javascript on the page but it is just a complete HTML page there must be only javascript so what usually is in the script tags

Comment: I just found that the bundle.js is not compiled, which is very strange since, both AWS beanstalk instances run the exact same code and version.

Comment: What error did it give on compile it could be an unlucky connection error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the relevant javascript code in bundle.js It looks like an index.html without content this could be due to overwriting the file on accident or that you have some compile errors in your tests

**Edit:**

you need to install the node modules this way ( in the console )

```
  npm i react-addons-shallow-compare
```

So it won't fail again it's just **missing** the module

Comment: Thanks! It indeed fixed it, but I don't understand why that problem just appears, in between deployments without us changing anything. Friday it was working fine and on the productions server it works fine.

Comment: Someone manually installed it in your production server ( probrably ) without communicating it with the rest of the team and forgot to list it in the depencies